# Não é possível carregar o arquivo ou assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Tags: .net, asp.net, web.config

Estou tentando abrir um projeto antigo em ASP.NET na minha máquina e estou obtendo o seguinte erro quando tento executá-lo para visualizar no browser:

> ```
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
>
> Source Error: 
>
> Line 8:      <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
> Line 9:        <assemblies>
> Line 10:         <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
> Line 11:         <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
> Line 12:         <add assembly="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
>
> Source File: C:\Users\visualstudio\Downloads\MPN\web.config    Line: 10 
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
> ```

Comment: Você já conferiu nas referências do projeto pra ver se essa dll está lá?

Comment: Hum...não...vou dar uma olhada em como verifico isso.

Comment: Se você está usando o Visual Studio, clique com o botão direito no projeto, clique em "Property Pages". Vai abrir uma janela com todas as referências.

Comment: Sim, a referência com o nome Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel se encontra lá. Mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.